# Disable F5 in Firefox during development

Tags: firefox

When doing development and using breakpoints, sometimes i happen to use F5 on the browser instead of Visual Studio as intended. This refreshes the page and breaks the debug chain. Is there any way of disabling the F5 shortcut for refresh in Firefox during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/?src=search would seem to do what you want just about. You can't use it to disable shortcuts but you could remap refresh to some other key than F5.